# $_SESSION display not reflecting changes after hitting submit once

Tags: php, variables, session, submit

I'm creating a profile page where the name of the user can be edited. I can't seem to figure out how to update the name of the user that is displayed at the top page (i.e. Hi Kana!) after a successful edit.

The name is generated using a session variable at the top of my page, **$_SESSION['username']**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_SESSION['newusername'])){
    unset($_SESSION['username']); //clear existing username session
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_SESSION['newusername']; //replace with the new username
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
} else {
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
}
?>
```

After hitting the submit button with a different name set on the text input it should change but it does not. These are the lines of codes after the code I mentioned above.

```
<?php
$textinput = $_POST['textinput']; 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if(strlen($_POST['textinput']) < 2)) {
$errormessage = 'too short';
}
else
{
$_SESSION['newusername'] = $textinput; //setup a new session for the new username to be used above.
}
}
?>
```

Note that the two quoted set of codes are in the same page.

What happens is that the name still shows the previous name, which is supposedly overwritten. I tried refreshing the page but it still does not change, I need to submit again (2nd time) to show the new name.

Comment: *"the two quoted set of codes are in the same page"* - Then one of two things is true... Either you're outputting the value before trying to change it, or you're trying to change it before starting the session.

Comment: It is absolutely unnecessary to check if the entry in the session exists first, and then try to unset it (which is written with only one `s` btw., so the code you have shown here would likely not even work) - you can just overwrite it with your new value.

Comment: But it is necessary to `session_start()` in all scripts

Comment: And writing the value into `newusername`, only to transfer it to `username` then in a second step, is also quite superfluous.

Comment: `unsset()` does not exist ???

Comment: In one code snippet you check `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`, but in another you check `if($_POST['submit'])`.  Why the difference?

Comment: _Small Note_ The `isset()` function will test multiple items in one call like `if(isset($_POST['submit'], $_SESSION['newusername']){`

Comment: Its also simpler to just replace the existing value of a variable with another, you dont need to destroy it first.

Comment: okay let me check. @RiggsFolly, typo, changed it. I also edited the errors in the code, Sorry about that. Let me do some changes on my end with everyone's advice here.

Comment: `copy/paste` real code. Then we are debugging whats really there and not pseudo code

Comment: So when you initially load this code you shoudl be getting a Undefined Index error on this line `$textinput = $_POST['textinput'];` As you dont mention that, I assume you are developing on a live server and Error Display is turned off. **Thats always a BAD way to develop**

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: I got it to work now by assigning the $_POST['textinput'] directly to the session variable. Thanks. It only became complicated because I was trying to catch the submit success since even with wrong name entry the name changes because the condition is simply the submit click (i.e. length too short)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can and should *drastically* simplify your code.  Currently there are a variety of unnecessary operations here.  Consider semantically what you want to accomplish:

> If the user submits their name, update the session with the new value.  Then output the value.

That's it.  Let the semantics of what you want to accomplish guide how you accomplish it.  Start the session, check for the form post, conditionally update the value, output the current state of the value.  For example:

```
<?php
session_start();

// update the value
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['textinput'];
}

// output the value
echo $_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

Maybe you'll want to add a sensible default in the absence of a username.  That would just be something like:

```
<?php
session_start();

// set a default value
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = "Default User";
}

// update the value
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['textinput'];
}

// output the value
echo $_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

Comment: sorry about that. The reason I set a new session ($_SESSION['newusername']) is that checking the submit button by isset will change the name regardless if the name set is false, say the length is too short. But yeah, I did not include the validation in my pseudo-code, my fault.

Comment: @user874737: You can still add the validation here, there's no need for a second session variable.  Your code is over-complicating what you are attempting to do, and the result is that you're confusing yourself.  Simplify.  State in plain words the steps you want to follow, then write the code for those steps.

Comment: Okay. I made it work, I actually think I did make it work earlier. It only became like this because I was trying to catch the success of the submission and not trigger the change if the entry is incorrect, hence I went to set a new session since it is global. The $errormessage variable is getting an undefined index so I cannot catch it.

Comment: if you don't mind, how can I tell the first code to only change when submit is success without using another session? I asked it here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62047269/validation-variable-is-returning-an-empty-string. I also want to avoid using $_GET.

Comment: @user874737: It's not clear what you're asking, and that question sounds like a different issue (trying to use a variable before it's defined).

Comment: nvm, probably my logic is wrong. I'll see what I can do. Thanks anyway. :)